# Simplification after chain rule differentiation of: $\frac{1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm hitting my head against the wall here trying to figure this out... had to determine the derivative of $\,\,\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)$. That part was easy enough, chain rule a bit and ended up with:
$$\dfrac{1+\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

... but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get it to simplify. I know that it SHOULD come out to
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

, but I can't figure out how in the world to get there. I've tried separating out the two added terms, tried multiplying by $\dfrac{x-\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x-\sqrt{x^2+1}}$, everything I do just seems to make it more complicated.

Comment: **Hint:** $1+\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$.

Comment: Ah, duh! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. It would be nice of you to answer your own question so this doesn't come as unanswered.